# Viewing errors on ogr2ogr - python subprocess check_output returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, subprocess, ogr2ogr

I am getting this error on running a subprocess.check_call that runs an ogr2ogr command.

I have put on error trapping but can't see the error details and the cmd window closes without me being able to see the problem.

How can I trace the problem?

The screen grab shows the working code (when typed in), the python script and the output of python shell.

One issue maybe the ' in the python generated code. The command is built based on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154004/execute-ogr2ogr-from-python/246667 where each option is wrapped in "[OPTION]",

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with a colleague...

Needed to

1. Load this in a batch shell that had the paths to ogr
2. Trust that subprocess takes care of the extra "EPSG:23555" when required and not do "\"EPS...\"" to get the code to be the same as what runs in OSGEO4W Shell.
3. Running the .py file from powershell rather than IDLE/Pyscripter